# React-Router - Show Details From a Specific ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-router

Im making a simple portfolio, using react-router.

I have a Index page **"/"** and a Works Page **"trabalhos/"** that display all of my works.

The objective is when i click the Show More Button on the Works Page, i want to go to a single page that displays only that work.

Im using `<Route path="trabalhos/:id" component={TrabalhosShow} />` to pass via props the id to my new page.

Now the objective is to show the details of that work.

Need Help.

Thanks

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

import App from './components/app';
import Index from './components/index';
import Trabalhos from './containers/trabalhos';
import TrabalhosShow from './containers/trabalhos_show';

export default (
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={Index} />
    <Route path="trabalhos" component={Trabalhos}/>
    <Route path="trabalhos/:id" component={TrabalhosShow} />
</Route>
);
```

**trabalhos.js (List of Works)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';


class Trabalhos extends Component {
        handleClick(trabalho){
            browserHistory.push({
                pathname: "trabalhos/" + trabalho.id,
                state: {trabalhoDetails: trabalho}
            });
    }

    renderList(){

        return this.props.trabalhos.map((trabalho) => {
            return(

                <li key={trabalho.id}>                 
                        <img src={trabalho.img} />
                        <p className="trabalho_titulo">{trabalho.title}</p>
                        <p className="trabalho_desc">{trabalho.descricao}</p>
                        <span className="trabalho_saber_mais" onCLick={this.handleClick.bind(this, trabalho)}>Saber Mais</span>
                </li>

            );
        });
    }


    render(){

        return (

            <div>
                <div className="trabalhos">
                    <div className="trabalhos_caixa">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xs-12">
                                <ul className="no_pad">
                                    {this.renderList()}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){

    return {

        trabalhos: state.trabalho

    };
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Trabalhos);
```

**trabalhos_show.js (Single Work)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class TrabalhosShow extends Component {


    render(){

        let jobDetails = this.props.location.state.trabalhoDetails

        let title = jobDetails.title;

        let desctription = jobDetails.descricao;

        return (

                <div>
                    <img src={jobDetails.img} />
                    <p className="trabalho_titulo">{title}</p>
                    <p className="trabalho_desc">{descricao}</p>
                </div> 
            );
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
   return {
       trabalhos: state.trabalho
   };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TrabalhosShow);
```

**reducer_trabalhos**

```
export default function() {

    return [

        { id: 1, title: 'Miristica', tec: "Wordpress-Woocommerce", descricao: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", img: 'http://feiraalternativa.pt/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Miristica-Bio-Cosm%C3%A9tica.png'},
        { id: 2, title: 'Teste', tec: "Wordpress-Woocommerce", descricao: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", img: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/766360293953802240/kt0hiSmv.jpg'},

    ];

}
```

**reducer Index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import TrabalhoPortofolio from './reducer_trabalhos';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    trabalho: TrabalhoPortofolio
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Thank You !

Comment: in your `trabalhos_show`, get the state again then filter the id

Comment: So what is your problem? getting user id?

Comment: Hello, i want to show the details of the specific work i click, if i click on work 1 i want to see that work, and so on. How can i pass the info to my trabalhos_show.js (Single Work) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect your detail page to the redux store and filter it via the ID.

Your trabalhos_show.js should be as follows :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class TrabalhosShow extends Component {


    render(){
        let jobDetails = this.props.trabalhos.filter( t => t.id == this.props.params.id)[0];
        return (
                <div>
                    <img src={jobDetails.img} />
                    <p className="trabalho_titulo">{jobDetails.title}</p>
                    <p className="trabalho_desc">{jobDetails.descricao}</p>
                </div> 
            );
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
   return {
       trabalhos: state.trabalho
   };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TrabalhosShow);
```

**The other solution** would be to add `onClick` event and pass the job details via `browserHistory`.

In trabalhos.js you should change your link to :

```
<span className="trabalho_saber_mais" onCLick={this.handleClick.bind(this, trabalho)}>Saber Mais</span>
```

It should look like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';


class Trabalhos extends Component {
        handleClick(trabalho){
            browserHistory.push({
                pathname: "trabalhos/" + trabalho.id,
                state: {trabalhoDetails: trabalho}
            });
    }

    renderList(){

        return this.props.trabalhos.map((trabalho) => {
            return(

                <li key={trabalho.id}>                 
                        <img src={trabalho.img} />
                        <p className="trabalho_titulo">{trabalho.title}</p>
                        <p className="trabalho_desc">{trabalho.descricao}</p>
                        <span className="trabalho_saber_mais" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, trabalho)}>Saber Mais</span>
                </li>

            );
        });
    }


    render(){

        return (

            <div>
                <div className="trabalhos">
                    <div className="trabalhos_caixa">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xs-12">
                                <ul className="no_pad">
                                    {this.renderList()}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){

    return {

        trabalhos: state.trabalho

    };
}



export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Trabalhos);
```

And then in `trabalhos_show.js` you can use the state which you passed with browserHistory like :

```
let jobDetails = this.props.location.state.trabalhoDetails
```

And then you can get all what you have inside trabalho like :

```
let title = jobDetails.title;
let desctription = jobDetails.descricao;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Boky, it Works, thank you very much for your help, the first solution works very well but the second one gives-me " Cannot read property 'trabalhoDetails' of null(…) " Thank You

Comment: @Hseleiro Glad that I could help. If you click on `Saber Mais` does it go to the detail page or not?

Comment: No, it does not go to the detail page, i go to the detail page by put trabalhos/1 and i get the error : " Cannot read property 'trabalhoDetails' of null(…) "

Comment: @Hseleiro Did you import `browserHistory`?

Comment: Yes, i will update my trabalhos_show.js on my question for you to see if im doing ok .

Comment: @Hseleiro In `trabalhos_show.js` you don't need browserHistory. You don't use it there. Update also `trabalhos.js`

Comment: @Hseleiro It should be `onClick` not `onCLick`. I am probably made a mistake. With `onClick` it should work.

Comment: Its Working :D !! Thank You very Much !! Really appreciated